# extract text using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

one of my elements from xml is an image and

when i do `<xsl:value-of select="MyImage" />` it outputs this as the data

```
<img alt="" border=0 src="/PublishingImage/myPic.jpg" style="border:0px solid">
```

using xslt can i extract just the src bit so that i have /PublishingImage/myPic.jpg
without the quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="img/@src" />
```

for a string inside an xml node try this

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(MyImage, 'src=&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
```

Josh

Comment: When I do: <xsl:value-of select="MyImage" /> it outputs the above, so how do I do it from there?

Comment: can you supply the xml for me to see. is the above data xml or a string in a xml node?

Comment: try now - replaced with &quot;